# Stripe Webhook Not logging event data but I see event data on stripe dashoboard

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAGvt.png)

The event data isnt logging but I can see it on stripe dashboard. Here is the code

```
import Stripe from "stripe";
import { buffer } from "micro";
import { useUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { user } = useUser();
  const fullName = user ? user.fullName : "";
  // console.log('Received POST request', req.body); // Log all incoming POST requests
  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const buf = await buffer(req);
    const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];
    const webhookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;

    let event;

    try {
      if (!sig || !webhookSecret) return;
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf, sig, webhookSecret);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Webhook error: ${error.message}`);
      return res.status(400).send(`Webhook error: ${error.message}`);
    }
    console.log("event", event);

    res.status(200).send();
    
}
}
```

I tried console logging error but no luck. the status code is not eve showing up is it because it is on test mode?.

Comment: If you're testing locally, did you forward the webhook events to your local webhook endpoint? i.e. did you use `stripe listen --forward-to` as mentioned in https://stripe.com/docs/development/dashboard/local-listener

Comment: yes i did i even added it as a script  "stripe:listen": "stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/api/webhooks"

Comment: are you able to make a request to that endpoint yourself? what happens if you do so? e.g. `curl localhost:3000/api/webhooks -X POST`

Comment: let me that right now

Comment: @alex i get this error

 ✓ Compiled /_error in 617ms (1323 modules)
 ⨯ Detected default export in '/Users/ayomidehakeem/Desktop/Creator Kit/frontend-vg/src/app/api/webhook/route.js'. Export a named export for each HTTP method instead.
 ⨯ No HTTP methods exported in '/Users/ayomidehakeem/Desktop/Creator Kit/frontend-vg/src/app/api/webhook/route.js'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.
 ✓ Compiled in 261ms (1323 modules)

Comment: I am using NextJs and Clerk Auth